# How to modify this macro in common lisp to integrate collect in loop?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, sbcl

I have a macro below that iterates along bits in an integer. I would like to integrate the collect capability of the loop like this:

```
 (loop for x in '(a b c d e)
      for y in '(1 2 3 4 5)
      collect (list x y) )
```

How should I modify the macro below to accomplish the above?

```
(defmacro do-bits ((var x) &rest body)
  "Evaluates [body] forms after binding [var] to each set bit in [x]"
  (let ((k (gensym)))
    `(do ((,k ,x (logand ,k (1- ,k))))
         ((= ,k 0))
       (let ((,var (logand ,k (- ,k))))
         ,@body))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a simple macro `with-collector` that should do the trick:

```
(defmacro with-collector ((&optional (collector-name 'collect)) &body body)
  (let ((result (gensym)))
    `(let ((,result (list)))
       (flet ((,collector-name (arg) (push arg ,result)))
         (progn ,@body)
         (when ,result
           (nreverse ,result)))))
```

it uses the name `collect` by default:

```
(with-collector ()
  (collect 'a)
  (collect 'b)); => (A B)
```

but you can use another name if you like (e.g. for nesting or resolving a symbol conflict)

```
(with-collector (foo)
  (foo 'bar)
  (foo 'baz)); => (BAR BAZ)
```

to integrate it with your macro, just wrap the `do` form:

```
(defmacro do-bits ((var x) &rest body)
  "Evaluates [body] forms after binding [var] to each set bit in [x]"
  (let ((k (gensym)))
    `(with-collector ()
       (do ((,k ,x (logand ,k (1- ,k))))
           ((= ,k 0))
         (let ((,var (logand ,k (- ,k))))
           ,@body)))))
```

and `collect` will be available in the body:

```
(do-bits (x 255) (collect x))
; => (1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128)
(do-bits (x 256) (collect x))
; => (256)
```

Comment: So how should I integrate this with the macro i provided?

Comment: I think combining the macros like this would work: (with-collector () (do-bits ....))

Comment: I got this `; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The return value of NREVERSE should not be discarded.` When using do-bits without a return value. It seems I have to return something or else it won't work. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I didn't see that warning in ccl or sbcl, but I'm not using the latest version of either... edited the macro to check if any values have been accumulated before reversing the result. Does this eliminate your warning?

Comment: A very useful anaphoric macro Lex!